# In the N400 application or at USCIS naturalization interview, is it an issue if the address on one's driver license differ from one's current address?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork

In the N400 application or at USCIS naturalization interview, is it an issue if the address on one's driver's license is different from one's current address? Assume that the driver's license is provided as the ID during the interview.

My state requires me to inform the DMV of the address change but doesn't require me to obtain a new driver's license (unless the former address was in a different state).

Comment: In New York, there is a legal requirement to inform the DMV of an address change.  Should we assume that there is such a requirement in this case?  If so, should we assume that it has been complied with?  (There's no legal requirement to get a new license, but there's a space on the back to write in the current address by hand.  Good luck finding a pen that won't rub off.)

Comment: @phoog thanks, same here, I have to inform the DMV of the address change but no legal requirement to get a new driver's license (unless the former address was in a different state).

Comment: Well I would be completely unconcerned in that case, but then again I have no personal experience with naturalization interviewers, so maybe I should be wrong to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not an issue. The driving license is not an authority as to your living address. Your filed form AR-11 is (or whatever the address you gave to the CBP on your last entry to the US). If your AR-11 address doesn't match your current address - *then* you may have issues.